# Unable to get javascript dictionary in django view

Tags: python, ajax, django

here is the script

```
function submitForm(event , productId) {
          event.preventDefault(); 

          var discount = "";

          discount = $('#discount').val();

          console.log(parameter)

          $.ajax({        
              type: "POST",
              url: "{% url 'inventory' %}",
              data: { productId : productId , discount:discount , 'parameter[]':parameter, csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
              success: function(data) {

                }
              },
              error: function(response, error) {
                  alert(error);  
        }
    });
}
```

the parameter dictionary looks like this

```
Object {L: "2", M: "2"}
```

and then here is the view

```
def post(self, request , *args , **kwargs):

    sizes_list = request.POST.get('parameter[]')


    print sizes_list
```

the print statement is giving none.
Why it is so ? What can i do to resolve the above error
thank you

Comment: Why not `paramter: [parameter]` and `request.get('parameter')`?

Comment: it prints none again@ElwinArens

Comment: You might want to `JSON.stringify()` the nested object. Otherwise you will get form parameters ala `parameter[][L]=2` and the like.

Comment: How ? i did not get you properly

Comment: If `parameter` is a nested object, you will get POST data with the nested object deep encoded as form-parameters. If you use `'parameter[]': JSON.stringify(parameter)`, you will get the JSON-encoded array sent to django. Otherwise you will get individual form keys for the sub-elements of the array, e.g. `parameter[][L]=2` and `parameter[][M]=2`

Comment: i tried with json.stringify it sends some unusual escape characters